# Inside td, how to apply "text-overflow: ellipsis" to SOME elements, but not all?

Tags: html, css

For example, inside a td, I have "Product name" and "Description" shows as the following:

[image]

Which I want the "Product" have ellipsis only, but not "Description", I tried:

```html
    <table border="1" style="width:100%;">
      <tr>
        <td><img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/65756ce7bab4d76ac10456972dd9f21d?s=96&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1"/></td>
      <td>
      <p style="width:100%;max-width:0;overflow:hidden;text-overflow: ellipsis;white-space: nowrap;">Product name : very very very very very very very very very long product name</p>
      <p>Description : This is a paragraph about the product detail.</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

but it is not working. How can I do that?

Note: I found I can enclose the product with another table:

```html
<table border="1" style="width:100%;">
  <tr>
    <td><img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/65756ce7bab4d76ac10456972dd9f21d?s=96&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1"/></td>
    <td>
    <table style="width:100%;"><tr><td style="max-width:0;overflow: hidden;text-overflow: ellipsis;white-space: nowrap;">Product name : very very very very very very very very very long product name</td></tr></table>
    Description : This is a paragraph about the product detail.
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

but I think this solution is too complex, is there any simpler solution?

Comment: I'd stick to your solution

Answer (score 3):

For `text-overflow: ellipsis` to work you need to define `width` for element on which `text-overflow: ellipsis` should work. Below I placed snippet with your fixed code.

```html
<table border="1" style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td>
    <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/65756ce7bab4d76ac10456972dd9f21d?s=96&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <p style="width:300px;overflow:hidden;text-overflow: ellipsis;white-space: nowrap;">Product name : very very very very very very very very very long product name</p>
      <p>Description : This is a paragraph about the product detail.</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `table-layout:fixed;` to your `<table>` will fix your code.This is commonly happen when you are using `<table>` as a container.

by adding `table-layout:fixed;` to your `<table>` so that table and column widths are set by the widths of table and col or by the width of the first row of cells. What it will do is that the `<td>` will detect the width of `<table>` and the `text-overflow: ellipsis` will trigger based on the width of the `<table>`.

**Solution 1:**

You can set the width of the first column `<td>` and `<img>` so that the `<img>` width will be responsive.

```html
<table border="1" style="width:100%;
  table-layout:fixed;">
      <tr>
        <td style="width:20%;"><img style="width:100%;" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/65756ce7bab4d76ac10456972dd9f21d?s=96&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1"/></td>
      <td>
      <p style="overflow:hidden;text-overflow: ellipsis;white-space: nowrap;">Product name : very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long product name</p>
      <p>Description : This is a paragraph about the product detail.</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

**Solution 2:**

You can set the width of second column `<td>` and `<img>` so that the `<img>` width will be responsive.

```html
<table border="1" style="width:100%;
  table-layout:fixed;">
      <tr>
        <td><img style="width:100%" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/65756ce7bab4d76ac10456972dd9f21d?s=96&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1"/></td>
      <td style="width:80%">
      <p style="overflow:hidden;text-overflow: ellipsis;white-space: nowrap;">Product name : very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long product name</p>
      <p>Description : This is a paragraph about the product detail.</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```